# python-mysql fetchone() type mismatch?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have this piece of code that should return the value of the password from the db and match it with the password entered. I appended the characters on this line to match the formatting of the result that it printed.

```
appended_y= "(u'" + y + "'y,)"
```

it even though the two print out the same value the if statement rejects it and always falls to else, Can anyone point me down the right path?

```
print "Welcome to the online bookstore login!"
    x = raw_input('Please enter your user id. ')
    y = raw_input('Please enter your password. ')
    appended_y= "(u'" + y + "'y,)"  
    z = "SELECT password FROM members WHERE userid = %s"
    self.cursor.execute(z,(x,))
    pw=(self.cursor.fetchone())

    if appended_y == pw:
        self.member_menu()
    else:
        print "Incorrect name or password. Aborting connection"
```

Comment: Look into the type of `pw`.  It may be a string inside a list or tuple.

Comment: It was a tuiple instead of a string. :)

Comment: @vpit3833 Why did you delete your answer? It was correct!

Comment: @glglgl, it was a mistake.  thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the type of `pw`.  It may be a string inside a list or tuple.